# Creating Virtual Machine from VMWare data store

Tags: vmware

One of the teams which we collaboratively working, has shared virtual images through VMware Data store. Now the only option I could find is to download the data to the local disk and and create the images from it. Is it possible to create datastore itself without downloading it?